# win_ros on debian squezze

Tags: ros, win-ros, rosinstall, debian, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install the win_ros packages in order to have a cross-compiling build environment for mingw programs. I was following the guide (in http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Windows) but I get this error:

```
/srv/ros$ rosinstall /srv/ros http://code.google.com/p/win-ros-pkg/source/browse/stacks/win_ros/trunk/winmaster_diamondback.rosinstall
rosinstall operating on /srv/ros from specifications in rosinstall files /srv/ros/.rosinstall, http://code.google.com/p/win-ros-pkg/source/browse/stacks/win_ros/trunk/winmaster_diamondback.rosinstall
ahhhhhhhh, yaml parse error: mapping values are not allowed here
in "<file>", line 46, column 28
Usage: rosinstall PATH [<options> ...] [URI]...

rosinstall: error: None
```

Are there any other requirement to use correctly this rosinstall command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9726/win_ros-on-debian-squezze/) by [aperez](https://answers.ros.org/users/423/aperez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that the URL you are using is the HTML rendering of the rosinstall file. You have to use the raw file (there is a "view raw file" link on that page). Using the following line, it works:

```
rosinstall /srv/ros http://win-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/win_ros/trunk/winmaster_diamondback.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1